# What is the meaning of this line of code in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, arrow-functions

```
_counterState createState() => _counterState();
```

So I know what `=>` does. It is an arrow function, and a shorthand version of curly braces + return.

So this line is essentially returning `_counterState()`

What I don't understand is why is there `_counterState` before `createState()`. What does it mean? I know `createState` is a function in Flutter.

I am a beginner in coding and know basics. Although this line confused me alot. Can you guys please help?

I will provide any other additional info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like _counterState or bool, String, int etc. means the function return type which is before function f.e.

`int returnNumber() => 2;`
It means that the function "RetrunNumber" will return a value which is a int.

More info you will find: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program